# Do I need command prompt every time to open Jenkins?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have installed Jenkins through jenkins.war file. Every time it depends upon command prompt to start Jenkins on web page. After running **java -jar jenkins.war** I can open Jenkins. If I am closing command prompt and refreshing the `http://localhost:8080/` then it shows error "localhost refused to connect".
Is there any permanent solution?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: window 10 @SteveSmith

Answer (score 2):

Jenkins is being deployed as a [.war file](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi8tZXA5-DVAhUDQY8KHeYJA4kQFggpMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FWAR_(file_format)&usg=AFQjCNGP2veppfc49JCKGy7aFJSUD_zbIw).This would mean it is being run as a webapp with tomcat( port 8080). Tomcat either needs to be run from cmd or as a service. If you want to make it easier, [add it as a service](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjH_czN6ODVAhVK9GMKHcQ5AYMQFggpMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F5920051%2Finstalling-tomcat-7-as-service-on-windows-server-2008&usg=AFQjCNGHqXYl-1xzY7u2_m110uhBWM5-Kw) and [enable it to be run at startup.](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwih3ZDp6ODVAhVX6GMKHUy2AIEQFggpMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ibm.com%2Fsupport%2Fknowledgecenter%2FSSJJ9R_6.0.1%2Fcom.ibm.jazz.install.doc%2Ftopics%2Fm_s_server_installation_start_tomcat.html&usg=AFQjCNF3gmHK3u-u5HjK_y99WAFYCFmDyw)

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your war file to a appliation server like tomcat, jboss etc or you can install jenkins as a service.

[Here](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/getting-started/installing/) is the official documentation to install jenkins in any OS